# Combining exposure variable

Tags: regression, logistic

I have few exposure variables (from a survey N= 1241) two of which are 1) dichotomous response of the question: "Did you have enough water in past 30 days?" and 2) dichotomous response of "Have you spent 2 or more days without water in past 30 days?". I want to run logistic regression to see if they are related with disease outcome in the families. Now, if I combine these two variable into one: "yes"= had both enough water and did not spend days without water and "no"= either one or both of the above questions were "yes", am I doing anything wrong? Is it statistically okay to do so? Some other variables are water quality test result, access to toilet, hand washing practices etc. I don't have income data.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with rhat. To get some more useful answer, we need more details, like How do you obtain your data? Sample size? Some othervariables you do observe?

Comment: Thank you. The data came from a household survey, N= 1241; some other variables are water quality test result, access to toilet, hand washing practices etc.

Comment: Can you please add that new information to the original post, so the post is complete? That is the expected standard here!   Do you have data on income or otherwise SES (socio-economic standard). Or all this are poos households, probably?

Comment: I would try to use logistic regression with those control variables included.